# svn commit error

Tags: svn

When I commit a change to the Ubuntu Subversion, I always get the error below.

```
~$ sudo svn commit -m "Initial Commit" test.txt --username akira

svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't open file '/home/svn/myrepo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

How should I set the permission to the txn-current-lock?
I set the permissions below beforehand.

```
~$ sudo chown -R taro:subversion myrepo
~$ sudo chmod -R g+rws /home/svn/myrepo
```

Comment: How is your repository initialized? I.e. what command like `svn co ...` (or `svn checkout`) have you ran?

Comment: svn://, svn+ssh:// or http:// repo?

Comment: The command was 'sudo svn co http://192.168.253.130/svn/repository /home/akira/svn/repository --username akira'

Comment: Wait, you're committing *as root*, and you get a permission denied error?  Weird.  Is /home mounted over NFS or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said:

> The command was `sudo svn co http://192.168.253.130/svn/repository /home/akira/svn/repository --username akira`

That means that you're checking out from the server `192.168.253.130` over HTTP to the local directory /home/akira/svn/repository as user `akira`. The read/write privileges on the SVN server (a centralized repository) are determined by the program serving SVN over HTTP (likely Apache). Apache is running as `www-data` and cannot write to `/home/svn/myrepo/db/txn-current-lock` if it's not owned by you.

I suggest you to start a svnserve daemon as the `svn` user and use that instead of Apache. The URL `http://192.168.253.130/svn/repository` then becomes something like `svn://192.168.253.130/myrepo` when using [this initscript](http://pastebin.com/jqp7CN0p) that basically invokes `svnserve --root=/home/svn --threads` as user `svn`. If you're running a local subversion server, you can add the `--listen-host=localhost` option for added security.

Comment: When using svn:// protocol, some case is successful and another case fails.

Comment: When using svn:// protocol, some case is successful and another case fails. On the server, [svnserve -d --root=/home/svn --threads] is started as the user of svn. And on the client, [svn co svn://***] and [svn add ***] succeed but [svn commit] fails with the error of [Authorization failed]. I am confused. Could you give me another hint?

Comment: Have a look in the files in `/home/svn/myrepo/db/conf/`, especially the `passwd` file and `anon-access`/`auth-access` settings